Jacobian of a Null Space
So I am working toward constructing an algorithm that involves the null space of a matrix. The matrix is $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and has a rank $r < N$. I can obtain a left null space $\mathbf{A}_\perp \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times (r-N)}$ such that $\mathbf{A}_\perp' \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$. If I have some identification restrictions on $\mathbf{A}_\perp$, for instance, that the top $(r-N) \times (r-N)$ is the identity matrix, what techniques could I use to obtain the jacobian of this null space transformation? I am not sure exactly where to start, having gone through the Matrix Cookbook and similar resources. Thanks!
